# Segmentation fault when appending child to document fragment

Tags: php, xslt, segmentation-fault

I have the following PHP function which is called from an XSLT script. The goal is to filter a selection of nodes based on their dates.

```
function filter_feed($nodes)
{
    if( ! $nodes || ! count($nodes))
        return '';

    $r = $nodes[0]->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();

    if($r === FALSE)
        exit('failed to create document fragment');

    $limit = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next Saturday'));

    foreach($nodes as $n)
        if($n->getAttribute('date') <= $limit)
            $r->appendChild($n); // (!)

    return $r;
}
```

The XSLT line of XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="php:function('filter_feed', //week)/*">
    <xsl:sort select="@date" order="descending" />
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

This works perfectly on my machine and at webhost A. But at webhost B we get a segmentation fault:11 at the linje marked with `(!)`. I simply do not understand why, and the support guys at webhost B don't understand anything either.

Have anyone here experienced this? What are possible reasons for this fault? Am I doing something wrong or shaky here?

I am doing something similar that works fine in a different place: Get ownerDocument, create fragment, append childs and return. The difference is that there I am creating *new* elements. In the function listed above I'm appending childs that are already part of the document. Am I doing that incorrectly? If so, how should I be doing this?

Really hope someone have some pointers here, cause I'm completely lost :S

Comment: you need error checking in your code. `createDocumentFragment();` returns `FALSE` if an error occurs, make sure that `$r` is not false before you continue.

Comment: @RedAlert Wouldn't that cause a more "normal" kind of error though? Tried adding a check, but `$r` isn't `FALSE` there as far as I can see. (Updating question with the check)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic. Please report PHP bugs to http://bugs.php.net.

Comment: @NikiC I don't know if it is a PHP bug or not. Might be. Might also be a bug with Apache. Or simply me doing something that is a bit unsafe and really should be done in a different way.